# Is there a 'template' for a Rails web app with user authentication?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Is it possible to use a preexisting Rails app (preferably one that only has the user authentication system already setup) as a template by changing it to do what you want it to do?

I was hoping that there is something like wordpress is for php, that I can add to to make it do what I want it to do. Wordpress already has the user authentication and other important things built in. I can then go in and make it do what I want.

This question might reveal a fundamental misunderstanding of the framework concept, but I had to ask.

p.s. - Another way to ask this question could be "Can I take a basic Rails app with user authentication and then refactor it and add my own models?"

Comment: It almost seems like you are looking for a Content Management System that can be extended.  If so, have a look at these options: https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/content_management_systems

Comment: You can use one of the existents application building templates in the web for creating an devise ready application

Comment: Yes, that seems to be in the right direction. Is there a tool that can help me rename things? For instance, if I want to make a user contributed Spanish/English dictionary, how can I rename everything that says "post", including the database tables, to say "definition" (or something like that)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These two solutions appear to be what I am looking for:

https://github.com/RailsApps/rails-composer/

and

http://blog.bryanbibat.net/2011/01/03/starting-a-professional-rails-app-with-haml-rspec-devise-and-web-app-theme/

I will go through the tutorials and report back.

Comment: I started with Rails Composer and it has helped me to get a good base application.